# Debezium Connect does not create topic

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm a newbie to Kafka and started experimenting. I'm using this tutorial https://medium.com/high-alpha/data-stream-processing-for-newbies-with-kafka-ksql-and-postgres-c30309cfaaf8
I ran the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'debezium/postgres:11'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    command: postgres -c config_file=/home/config/postgresql.conf
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'C:\postgres-kafka\config:/home/config'
      - 'C:\postgres-kafka\config\pg_hba.conf:/home/config/pg_hba.conf'
      - 'C:\postgres-kafka\data\:/home/data/'
  zookeeper:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.2'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  schema-registry:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.1.2'
    hostname: schema-registry
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8082'
  ksql-server:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.1.2'
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
      KSQL_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8088'
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8082'
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: ksql-server
  connect:
    image: mtpatter/debezium-connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my-connect-configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my-connect-offsets
      ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE: 'true'
   # Runs the KSQL CLI
  ksql-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.2.2
    container_name: ksql-cli
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - ksql-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true
```

As described in the example,I created two tables "admission" and "research" in the "students" db in postgres,and filled them with values, copied from csv files.
After creating the tables I created a connector with the following configuration:

```
{"name": "postgres-source",
  "config": {"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "students",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "students",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.students",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8082",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope"   
  }
}
```

The connector exists but when I check the topics list, there are no topics for the two postgres table. I tried to create the connector first and then the tables and vice versa but no way.
Somebody suggested to disable the automatic topic creation for the Kafka broker and to enable it in at Connect level, see [debezium docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html#topic-creation-groups).

By checking the connect logs, I see this error:

```
2023-11-04 17:18:50,198 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres-source-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot create replication connection
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.<init>(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:89)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.<init>(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:39)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$ReplicationConnectionBuilder.build(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:409)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresTaskContext.createReplicationConnection(PostgresTaskContext.java:66)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.<init>(RecordsStreamProducer.java:82)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsSnapshotProducer.<init>(RecordsSnapshotProducer.java:75)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.createSnapshotProducer(PostgresConnectorTask.java:141)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:94)
        at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:47)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:163)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.<init>(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:81)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
        at org.postgresql.replication.fluent.logical.LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.make(LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.java:48)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:124)
        ... 17 more
2023-11-04 17:18:50,199 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres-source-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
```

Any hint is welcome !

Comment: Seems like you're running an older version of Kafka, and possibly Connect API which may not create topics, but also, if it cannot read your database tables, there's no reason for it to make topics to produce data into, so you'll need to solve those first from the Postgres side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **"auto.topic.creation.enable"** config is not set to true, kafka will not create topics automatically. So you have the choice to either activate the creation by setting the config **"auto.topic.creation.enable"** to true or creating manually the topics needed.

So if you want kafka to create topics automatically, you need to change the value of ***KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE*** in your docker compose

Comment: Thanks a lot, that change in my docker-compose.yml  worked!

KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical

Change the parameter wal_level to logical and restart.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Ihad inadvertedly overwritten the docker postgres.conf with my own file where wal_level was set to replica. The above error is gone.
Unfortunately, topics are not yet created, now I get the following error:

 [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3964 : {dbserver1.public.research=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]

I'm opening a separate thread for that

Thanks