# Kafka Unknown Topic Or Partition

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm a newbie to Kafka and started experimenting. I'm using this tutorial https://medium.com/high-alpha/data-stream-processing-for-newbies-with-kafka-ksql-and-postgres-c30309cfaaf8 I ran the following docker-compose.yml

As described in the example,I created two tables "admission" and "research" in the "students" db, schema "public",and filled them with values, copied from csv files.
After creating the tables I created a connector with the following configuration:

```
{"name": "postgres-source",
  "config": {"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "students",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "students",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.students",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8082",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope"   
  }
}
```

Checking the Connect log I see that topics are not created and the following error is thrown:

> [Producer clientId=producer-5] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3964 : {dbserver1.public.research=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]

I searched the Internet about this error but I'm still stuck. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was posted  by SaraM. in my previous thread:
[Debezium Connect does not create topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77422969/debezium-connect-does-not-create-topic/77426827#77426827)

> So if you want kafka to create topics automatically, you need to
> change the value of KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE in your docker
> compose

Comment: Do not post a link as answer. Just share the post link in the commecnts